# Does RDD's .first() method shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine, we have small_table and big_table, and need do this:

```
small_table.join(big_table, "left_outer")
```

Could it be faster if i do this:

```
small_table.map(row => {
   val find = big_table.filter('id === row.id)
   if (find.isEmpty) return Smth(row.id, null)
   return Smth(row.id, find.first().name)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were able to access the data of one RDD inside a mapping of another RDD, you could run some performance tests here to see the difference. Unfortunately, the following code:

```
 val find = big_table.filter('id === row.id)
```

is not possible, because this attempts to access the data of one RDD inside another RDD.